# Store result of numeric expression in SAS macro variable

Tags: sas

I am using SAS Enterprise guide and want to store the result of a small calculation in a SAS macro variable:

My code looks as follows:

```
%do quarter = 0 to 3; 
    %let macro_variable = &quarter. * 3; 
%end;
```

However, this results in the following errors in my code:

```
Statement is not valid, or it is used out of the proper order. Affected code: 0*3.
```

What am I doing wrong here? This seems like such a simple operation.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that causes this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro function %eval() lets you perform arithmetic with integer macro variables.

Try this:

```
%do quarter = 0 %to 3;
  %let macro_variable = %eval(&quarter. *3);
%end;
```

If you need a calculation for non integers then replace %eval with %sysevalf which uses floating point arithmetic